# java regex advice

Tags: java, regex, arrays

Can anyone please advice me how to apply regex on the following String so that it returns array or any collection of items that appear in angled brackets(<>)?

```
77+<99>*0.5+<100>+<101>+<99>*0.5+<100>+<101>
```

array will contain

```
{99,100,101,100,101};
```

Thanks!

Update:(following giving no match)

```
// Compile regular expression
String patternStr = "(?<=<)(\\d+)(?=>)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);

// Determine if there is an exact match
CharSequence inputStr = "77+<99>*0.5+<100>+<101>+<99>*0.5+<100>+<101>";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
boolean matchFound = matcher.matches(); // false
System.out.println("...log..."+matchFound);
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Here's a good visual tool to help you test and build (most) regexes.  
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex `(?<=<)(\d+)(?=>)` and then remove duplicates.

Comment: "$1," add only the ',' after the group

Comment: I am still unable to figure it out pls.